# Pass URL arguments from one URL to next in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url

Trying to achieve following, user opens url via email, url will lead him to:
`https://iderma.lt/?name=john`

He will then click button that will open next url: `https://form.typeform.com/to/sxmSCYSc?city=Vilnius`

That url already contains multimple of arguments, but I would want it to contain extra argument from the first url `&name=john`

Finally it would look like `https://form.typeform.com/to/sxmSCYSc?city=Vilnius&name=john`

How to achieve that?

Comment: So which of these two systems is actually WordPress? The former, the latter, both of them? WP has the handy function [`add_query_arg`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

if you use $_session maybe ?

Set up a 'get' at the reception of the email which stores the name then posted it with the sending of the city and finally add everything

in my opinion it's a story of [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get), [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post), and [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Yeah I assume this is not complex, I am not much into coding, just need for the simple solution I could add to my WordPress. Could you possibly help me out here?

Comment: Hello, 

`$name = $_GET[$name];`

your link -> 
`<a href="https://form.typeform.com/to/sxmSCYSc?city=Vilnius?name=<?=$name; ?>">`

it gives something like this